# Ajax request to laravel backend results in 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I never made an ajax request using laravel so it's different than just plain php.

This is my script that is attached on a dropdown onchange:

```
function createcomploadtemplate(){

var ifprefix = $("#createcomploadtemplatedropdown").find("option:selected").text();

var getidtemplate = $('#createcomploadtemplatedropdown').val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxfixedcompany',
        data: {getidtemplate:getidtemplate,ifprefix:ifprefix},
        dataType: 'json', 
        encode  : true,
        success: function(data){
           alert(data.success);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::post('ajaxfixedcompany',['middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'ajaxfixedcompany', 'uses' => 'AjaxController@ajaxfixedcompany']);
```

And this is the function

```
public function ajaxfixedcompanyget(Request $request){
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => $request->message,
    );

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

If i use ajax url /ajaxfixedcompany instead of ajaxfixedcompany in chrome devtools i get "The page doesnt exist" with error 404

And without the / i get this:

[image]

EDIT: OMG...I think i just needed a break from all this. I have 2 controllers. 1 for POST and 1 for GET. i am requesting a POST while in my controller i only have my GET function created... It works again. lmfao

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with csrf token.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url/update",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'id=' + id+ '&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException is a sign that your routes is working fine.

pls check the url, using the controllers name first.

here is the route example : Route::post('update', ['middleware' => 'web', 'uses' => 'UrlController@update'])->name('url.update');

Comment: Well it was a silly mistake by myself. When you mentioned "URL" i remembered that i had 2 controllers. 1 for GET and one for POST.
I was requesting a POST method while i only have the GET function in the controller...it works.. lmfao

Answer (score 0):

Well i just needed a break. After that 1hour break i came back and noticed that i am making a post request, while it is also called in my route, but i had a typo in my controller....silly me... lmfao